Powershell script: I have a CSV that I get with a list of emails and I want to iterate over it. to email each user separately
$CSV = "Rootfile.csv"  # creates a variable with the File location
$EmptyColumns = "Hired", "Manager Email" # Picks the columns with empty spaces to parse through
$userColumn = "User"
$managerColumn = "Manager Email"
$trimfile= "trimfile.csv"
$filterDate = (get-date).AddDays(1)

$data = import-csv $CSV | Where-Object{         # Removes the rows with blank columns   # Imports the file
    $line = $_
    ($EmptyColumns| ForEach-Object{
        ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty(($line.$_.Trim("""")))
    }) -notcontains $false
}

$selectedData = $data | select-object -Property 'Learner Email',"Manager Email", "Hired"     #This Selects the data from the imported file
$selectedData | Where-Object {$_.Hired -as [dateTime] -lt $filterDate} | Export-csv -path $trimfile #This filters the columns where the datetime is lt then todays date. Exports that filter file. 
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


$Use = Import-Csv $trimfiletest | Select-Object $userColumn
# $Mang = Import-Csv $trimfile | Select-Object $managerColumn

foreach ($user in $use){
  $ol = New-Object -comobject outlook.Application
  $newOl = $ol.CreateItem(0)
  $newOl.Recipients.add($user )
  $newOl.To = ($user)
  $newOl.type = 3
  $newol.subject = "                TEST                "
  $newol.body = "#############################################                 IGNORE                 ############################################# "
  $newOl.send()
}

I want to loop through a CSV array and for each leaner email send out a message to that person only on the list. Do that for every user. For some reason it's not reading the names or iterating in the way that I would like.

$user contains an object with a User property, so you want $user.User or $user.$userColumn

SetValueInvocationException:
Line |
29 |    $newOl.type = 3
|
| Exception setting "type": "The property 'type' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
InvalidOperation:
Line |
32 |    $newOl.draft()
|
| Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'draft'.
OperationStopped:
Line |
27 |    $newOl.Recipients.add($user.user)
 | There must be at least one name or contact group in the To, Cc, or Bcc box.

SetValueInvocationException:
Im getting this Error

I was able to get the emails but they all are blank.

The first error tells you exactly what's wrong - the MailItem object you have stored in $newOl doesn't have a type property, so attempting to assign a value to $newOl.type won't work. For the recipient, you don't need to manually modify $newOl.Recipients when you're already assigning a value to $newOl.To

I got it to work Thank you!
